# PHP Comparing variables returns false every time

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, mysqli

I have this *script* that checks a submitted form. 
It checks if all *fields* are all filled out, and checks if the user has submitted the form before. It also checks if the entered data is already in the database or not. 
When I try to check if the entered data is in the database, it always returns *false*. 
My question is: How can I efficiently check if the POST values are the same?

**Code**:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_NOTICE ^ E_ALL);
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$ID = $_POST['id'];
$Topic_1 = $_POST['1'];
$Topic_2 = $_POST['2'];
$Topic_3 = $_POST['3'];
$Topic_4 = $_POST['4'];
$Topic_5 = $_POST['5'];
$Topic_6 = $_POST['6'];
$Topic_7 = $_POST['7'];
$Topic_8 = $_POST['8'];
$Topic_9 = $_POST['9'];
$Topic_10 = $_POST['10'];
$Topic_11 = $_POST['11'];
$Topic_12 = $_POST['12'];
$Topic_13 = $_POST['13'];
$Topic_14 = $_POST['14'];
$Topic_15 = $_POST['15'];
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$Connect = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "Data");
$Check = 'SELECT * FROM Submissions WHERE School_ID = "'.$ID.'" AND IP = "'.$IP.'"';
$Insert = 'INSERT INTO Submissions (Name, School_ID, Topic_1, Topic_2, Topic_3, Topic_4, Topic_5, Topic_6, Topic_7, Topic_8, Topic_9, Topic_10, Topic_11, Topic_12, Topic_13, Topic_14, Topic_15, IP) VALUES ("'.$Name.'", "'.$ID.'", "'.$Topic_1.'", "'.$Topic_2.'", "'.$Topic_3.'", "'.$Topic_4.'", "'.$Topic_5.'", "'.$Topic_6.'", "'.$Topic_7.'", "'.$Topic_8.'", "'.$Topic_9.'", "'.$Topic_10.'", "'.$Topic_11.'", "'.$Topic_12.'", "'.$Topic_13.'", "'.$Topic_14.'", "'.$Topic_15.'", "'.$IP.'")';

if($Name && $ID != "")
{
    if($Result = $Connect->query($Check))
    {
        $Rows = $Result->num_rows;
        if($Rows == 0)
        {
            if($_POST != $_POST)
            {
                if($Go = $Connect->prepare($Insert))
                {
                    if($Go->execute())
                    {
                        echo 'Thanks';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'There Was An Error';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'There Was An Error';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'No Two Values Can Match.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'You Cant Vote Twice.';
        }
        $Result->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'There Was An Error.';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Please Fill Out All Fields';
}
$Connect->close();
```

Comment: Oh mercy that's an `else` disaster. I'll make an example of how to fix that...

Comment: What is is this supposed to do? `$_POST != $_POST`

Comment: And you're not using prepared statements. This is extremely dangerous code!!!

Comment: its not for a real website

Comment: please replace that Topic_1, Topic_2..bla bla, to a normal array. just do a $topics = array(); for($i=1; $i<10; $i++) {$topics[$i] = $_POST[$i];} // Now use topics array. like $topics[1];

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement should look like

```
if($name != "" && $check != "")
```

Comment: im not trying to see if they equal nothing im trying to see if they both equal

Comment: I tried out a demo script with the comparison you did, `if($Name && $Check != ""` and it always returned false. This was the solution I worked out.

Comment: By the way, using `empty` function is better than comparison with `""`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the error:

```
if($_POST != $_POST)
```

You do probably want to compare the result from the db with the $_POST instead.

```
$Row = $Result->fetch_assoc();
if($Row != $_POST)
```

Comment: im comparing that every $_POST doesnt match each other

Comment: No, `if($_POST != $_POST)` is comparing the array `$_POST` with itself which always is true.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to doing a comparison use var_dump() on the variables to check what they actually contain.

```
var_dump($Name);
var_dump($ID);
exit();
```

Then check for a negative or positive match.

```
if( !empty($Name) && empty($ID) ){
exit('ah, name filled in but not id ...');
}
```

You can even spoof that in a separate file.

```
<?php
$Name = 'Bob';
$ID = ''; // or use 0 or any test you want

var_dump($Name);
var_dump($ID);

if( !empty($Name) && empty($ID) ){
exit('ah, name filled in but not id ...');
}
```

Isolating problems like this will help you develop incrementally, get something working, then add more lines till you arrive at your destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really so easily check if a person did submit a form before.

One way is to add one more hidden field to form if the request came with POST.

Something like that:

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="second_post" value="1">'; 
        } ?>
        <!-- Other form items -->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="1">
    </form>
```

Then you can check is it a second time with:

```
if(isset($_POST['second_post'])) {
   // Second time of form post;
} else {
   // First (or zero) time post.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if not two POST values are the same:

```
array_diff($_POST, array_unique($_POST));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is following

```
$_POST['1'] = 'a';
$_POST['2'] = 'b';
$_POST['3'] = 'c';
$_POST['4'] = 'a';
$_POST['5'] = 'd';

$results = array_unique($_POST);
var_dump($results);
```

returns:

```
array
  1 => string 'a' (length=1)
  2 => string 'b' (length=1)
  3 => string 'c' (length=1)
  5 => string 'd' (length=1)
```